# How to migrate AndroidX to Android?

Tags: androidx

Because some cause,I must migrate AndroidX to Android many times(not Android to AndroidX!).Is there some easy way to solve it?one by one modify is not very convenient,even if it works.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: refer to this link:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57655435/what-replaced-appcompat-v7-in-androidx/57655709#57655709

Answer (score 0):

Just change your androidx dependency to use android.support library

Answer (score 0):

To migrate from androidx to android.support.

1. Set your **compileSdkversion and targetSdkversion to
   28.0.0**:

   Because it was the last feature release under
   android.support packaging and it makes migrating
   between compat and  androidx a one step process.
2. Remove the properties below from your **gradle.properties**
   file:

```
 android.useAndroidX=true
 android.enableJetifier=true
```

3. Upgrade you android studio to a version 3.2 or higher.
   So you can:  **Go to Refactor> Migrate to AppCompat.**