# What replaced appcompat-v7 in AndroidX

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-appcompat, androidx, material-components-android

After migrating a couple of my older projects over to AndroidX it as though three of my dependencies are deprecated:

```
   implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
   implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
   implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
```

I haven't been able to find a replacement for these dependencies.

Does AndroidX have an equivalent for these dependencies?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use in the order:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'   
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
```

If you would like to use **alpha/beta** releases:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha09'
```

More info about the releases:

- [AndroidX Releases](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/versions)
- [Material Components library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/releases)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, AndroidX has new Dependencies.

Use below implementation in your project

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
```

Instead of

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
```

and for more refer below link :-

- https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/artifact-mappings

and make sure before migrating the project to androidX.

> ***Steps to migrate Project (Very Easy)***

**1** : add gradle.properties file if doesn't exits. and add below line

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
```

**2** : goto refactor > Migrate to Android X

and do not change anything studio will automatically update all things

Answer (score 2):

New Android Design Libraries with androidx:

> AppCompat:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
```

> CardViex:

```
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
```

> However be careful because everything is not start with ***androidx***. For example, old *design* *dependency* is:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```

> Material:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
```

> Recyclerview:

```
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

See Migration guide, [Maven artifact mappings](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/artifact-mappings), your artifacts are listed there.